# How to deny write permission to a user group for few hours in SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

We have a bunch of queries that we run every month end. These queries store data from our production database into the reporting database.

There's a user group that has read/write access to the database and we want to deny just the write access only for 2 hours. Is that possible to have this process automated every end of month?

Comment: Depends on how you define "write access". There's no single "write" permission in T-SQL. Using the built-in `db_denydatawriter` role and adding the group to that role probably achieves what you want, if they're not admins -- scheduling this operation can be done with an SQL Server Agent job. A possible alternative to denying writes outright, depending on your scenario, is to use snapshot isolation to read the data you're interested in, or even a database snapshot, so the writes can proceed without affecting the consistency of the data you're reading.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could accomplish this is using 2 database roles.  One role is only read permissions and the other role is write permissions.  Add the user group to both roles.

Then via T-SQL in an agent job you can add and remove the group from the role that has the write permissions.

You'll use sp_addrolemember and sp_droprolemember:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-droprolemember-transact-sql
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addrolemember-transact-sql

Two jobs

- One for removing from the role

  ```
  EXEC sp_droprolemember N'RoleName', N'UserGroupName'
  ```
- Another for adding back to role

  ```
  EXEC sp_addrolemember N'RoleName', N'UserGroupName'
  ```

SQL Agent job scheduling page under frequency

- Occurs:  Monthly
- The last day of every 1 month(s)

Staggering the job schedules 2 hours apart.